# How append multiple dicto into a one dict python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-science

I develop with python and i have a multiple dictionnary like:

```
Dict1: {‘hi’:’340’, ‘hello’:’570’, ’me’:´800’}
Dict1: {‘hi’:’200’, ‘hello’:’100’, ’me’:´389’}
```

And i would like to add them together into a dict like:

```
Dict_new= { {‘hi’:’340’,‘hello’:’570’, ’me’:´800’},     {‘hi’:’200’, ‘hello’:’100’, ’me’:´389’}}
```

Finally i would likt to have this output:

```
 {‘elements’:{{‘hi’:’340’,‘hello’:’570’, 
                    ’me’:´800’},
                 {‘hi’:’200’, ‘hello’:’100’, 
                ’me’:´389’}}}
```

So what is the best mannee to do this ?

Comment: perhaps make it a list of dict rather than making dict of dict.

Comment: Do you want to `merge` the `dicts`? You can't add a dictionary to another dictionary because they are not a `hashable type`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `set`, please consider using a list which will store your dictionaries.

```
newDict = {}
newDict['element'] = [dict1,dict2]
```

output

```
{'elements': [{'hi': '340', 'hello': '570', 'me': '800'}, {'hi': '200', 'hello': '100', 'me': '389'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already used a list to store all my dict but i would like to store them in a dict instead of a list.

Comment: @Brun that wasn't a dict. That was a set.